# Clickable file with line number link in Intellij console output on Windows

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

Firstly, I'm using Intellij IDEA 2021.3.4 (Community Edition).

And in my project there is an XML file, and Java code which validates the XML files.

As part of the validation, if there is an error detected then the absolute file path and line number are printed to the console in the format:

```
file:///Users/rob/git/project/src/main/resources/com/app/test/Page.xml:6
```

I'm on Mac, and the log message is clickable. If I click on it then the IDE opens that file at the specified line number.

However, this same feature does not work when on Windows.

I've tried logging the message in various formats but none work.

Is the problem with the format of my log message, or just an issue with Intellij on Windows?

Various formats I've tried on windows:

```
file://C:\\Users\\rob\\git\\project\\src\\main\\resources\\com\\app\\test\\Page.xml:6
file://C:\\\\Users\\\\rob\\\\git\\\\project\\\\src\\\\main\\\\resources\\\\com\\\\app\\\\test\\\\Page.xml:6
file://C:/Users/rob/git/project/src/main/resources/com/app/test/Page.xml:6
```

Comment: Can you show the part of the code that generates that link?

Comment: I was thinking you might be generating the link wrong, but i have tested locally and it seems to work.
What i did notice though, is that a file uri with :6 at the end (like your sample), will not load.
Can you replace that with a hash? e.g file:///C:/Users/rob/source/repos/file.txt#6 ?

Comment: try https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7677-awesome-console